# How to store relational POCO's in nosql world?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

We' re working on a project that has a relational object model and we would like to use a no/sql solution (couchdb) for some part of data storage. For example, there are users and applications which are related to each other via Applications UserId field (Or User property in DDD world)

What is the right way to store "user" data in couchdb in an "Application" document? With id for relation or to put the entire "user" object in "application" document? If i put the entire "user" object in Application document, updating an user will cause to update all Application documents that has an entire user info inside it.

We' re little bit confused so i' ll be very happy to hear some ideas about that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either approach is valid, depending on what reads and writes you need - if the user object almost never changes, a slow/complex write process doesn't matter and you may be able to avoid a lot of extra reads by including it in the application document. If it changes a lot, the slow/complex writes become the dominant issue and it makes more sense to just put a reference in your application document. This is actually one of the bigger differences between SQL and NoSQL - SQL has one correct normalized structure, with NoSQL you need to think about your requirements more.

That said, user almost always makes sense as a standalone object. However, you aren't limited to using just the user id in your application document - including a display name (which rarely changes) probably eliminates almost as many reads as including the whole user object.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Do you have any idea what kind of model is used in social giants like twitter, facebook etc.? For example, when i check the twitter API document, most of API functions returns "documents" without id's. Is that mean that they are replacing id's with the actual "related document (object)" at runtime and return it to user after converting to json? Or they are storing actual "related object" in the document and they are resolving problems like slow/complex writes with powerful servers? Thank you!

Comment: What you see in an api like that doesn't have all that much to do with the underlying structure - for a large public api you usually have either data you want to keep private or internal optimizations you don't need to expose. The giants aren't really the best place to look for a clean architecture actually - they have all the complications that come from a few years of updating code, and I think still have a core of mysql with a ton of caching and optimization which includes nosql components that can be used standalone if starting from scratch.

Comment: so, putting id's or some identifier field for relations in documents is acceptable. what do you think about doing some extra work to replace id' s with the actual object values? i think we have to put some custom attributes to detect replacement in runtime...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using id links as you do in a relational database - the difference is that you don't need many of them since you have a better way to handle multivalue/complex fields. Your code will be more complex if you can't just grab a single document, but it is unlikely to come close to what you need to get complex objects out of sql tables. I wouldn't try to get too fancy about replacing values within a document - if it is a seperate document it usually makes sense to handle it seperately.